# MySQL Query to extract parameters present in procedure

Tags: mysql

I have some stored procedures in MySQL now I need to extract the SP name, SP parameters present in that Stored Procedure.

Through `information_schema.routines` I am able to extract only procedure names how to get parameters also.

Comment: Try ``SELECT `name`, `param_list` FROM `mysql`.`proc`;``.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply
I tried this but i got the error as
Select command denied for the use for table mysql.proc...
So now how can i get the permissions for that table.

Comment: You will need (at least) SELECT permission on the `proc` table in schema (database) `mysql`. See [13.7.1.4 GRANT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html).